# How to make buttons that adds or subtracts value inside input?

Tags: javascript, html, button, input, increment

I have an input that changes a paragraph's font size. The input changes the size of the paragraph whenever I enter things like "30px". I want it able to change when I only put the number of the size I want without needing to have "px" after it.

I also have 2 buttons next to it saying that adds or subtracts the value, but I cannot figure out how to make them change the value.

Obviously, I'd want this to all work without needing to have "px" after the number, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any help is appreciated.

My code:

```
<tr>
    <th>Text size (px):
        <input id="textSizeInput" type="text" value="20px">
        <button id="sizeChanger">Change</button>
        <button id="addTen">+10px</button>
        <button id="minusTen">-10px</button>
    </th>
</tr>
```

Javascript for the above code

```
var changeTextSize = function () {
    console.log('in changeTextSize');

    var newTextSize = document.getElementById("textSizeInput").value;

    document.getElementById("showText").style.fontSize = newTextSize;
}

document.getElementById('sizeChanger').onclick = changeTextSize;
document.getElementById('textSizeInput').onchange = changeTextSize;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an `click` event listener to each of the buttons which calls a function and increments the value of the input by a certain number.

To increment the value, get the value of the input, split by `"px"`, get the first item, increment it by the value, concatenate `"px"` then assign back to the input's value property:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("textSizeInput")
var changeTextSize = function() {
  console.log('in changeTextSize');

  var newTextSize = input.value;

  document.getElementById("showText").style.fontSize = newTextSize;
}

document.getElementById('sizeChanger').onclick = changeTextSize;
document.getElementById('textSizeInput').onchange = changeTextSize;

function increment(value){
  let currentValue = input.value.split("px")[0]
  input.value = +currentValue + value + "px";
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <th>Text size (px):
    <input id="textSizeInput" type="text" value="20px">
    <button id="sizeChanger">Change</button>
    <button id="addTen" onclick="increment(10)">+10px</button>
    <button id="minusTen" onclick="increment(-10)">-10px</button>
  </th>
</tr>

<p id="showText">Hello World!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any data validation or bounds checks:

```js
function increment() {
  const input = document.getElementById("textSizeInput");
  input.value = Number(input.value) + 10;
}
function decrement() {
  const input = document.getElementById("textSizeInput");
  input.value = Number(input.value) - 10;
}
```

```html
<tr>
    <th>Text size (px):
        <input id="textSizeInput" type="text" size="5" value="20"> px
        <button id="addTen" onclick="increment()">+10px</button>
        <button id="minusTen" onclick="decrement()">-10px</button>
    </th>
</tr>
```